# Ionic 2: Unable to trigger Interface change within Events subscribe function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic2, dom-events

In html, I have a simple text that I want to change when an event is publish.

**js**

```
this.state = "before";
var zoneA = this;
zoneA.state = "after";    <--- WORKS

zoneA.events.subscribe('done:connect', (userEventData) => {
  zoneA.state = "after";   <--- DOES NOT GET TRIGGERED
});
```

**html**

```
<div *ngIf="state == 'before'" class="beforePublish">Hello</div>
<div *ngIf="state == 'after'" class="afterPublish">Hello</div>
```

**css**

```
.beforePublish
{
  color: blue;
}

.afterPublish
{
  color: red;
}
```

When I call `zoneA.state = "after"` outside of `zoneA.events.subscribe(...);`, it works. But placing it inside does not trigger the change.

Anybody knows how to go about solving this?